# error to import graphx library in scala project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt, spark-graphx

When i use the following import statement in my Scala program, I am getting an error.[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em57Z.png)
Did i made any mistake with adding the libraryDependencies. For graphx.lib , is there any specific libraryDependencies to add.

import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths

Answer (score 0):

- Always add inline your config files - it is tricky to find the link to your image
- You mix spark library versions - always use one version of library

Try:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion,
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)
```